# Andoid emulator bug - mocking location problem

Tags: android, linux, dictionary, android-emulator

### **Andoid emulator bug - mocking location problem**

Hi! I can't set my location in android emulator, after analyzing logs I assumed, that the reason is a bug with a Google map API token, which occurred because of invalid callback(initMap:91), probably the response from maps.googleapis would be correct if the callback was set to just "initMap" (without ":91" postfix).

Have anyone seen such a bug? Please help if You figured out the solution.

**EMULATOR LOGS:**

```
INFO    | Android emulator version 32.1.14.0 (build_id 10330179) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found systemPath /opt/android-sdk/system-images/android-34/google_apis/x86_64/
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-xeempee/emu-crash.db, detection is enabled
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
INFO    | Info: Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway. ((null):0, (null))
Fontconfig warning: "/usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/05-reset-dirs-sample.conf", line 6: unknown element "reset-dirs"
WARNING | cannot add library /opt/android-sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed
INFO    | added library /opt/android-sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so
INFO    | Sending adb public key [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 xeempee@unknown]
WARNING | *** No gRPC protection active, consider launching with the -grpc-use-jwt flag.***
INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local, auth: none
INFO    | Advertising in: /run/user/1000/avd/running/pid_4022.ini
INFO    | Setting display: 0 configuration to: 320x640, dpi: 160x160
ERROR   | Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037
INFO    | Info: Sandboxing disabled by user. ((null):0, (null))
INFO    | Critical: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ? (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyABrfflV49aFWF4Kohsf1VSx68td8f-sFY&callback=initMap:91, (null))
```

**GOOGLEAPIS RESPONSE:**

```
// API callback
initMap:91({
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSONP callback name: 'initMap:91'; only alphabet, number, '_', '$', '.', '[' and ']' are allowed.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
);
```

**MACHINE INFO:**

`````
                   -`                    xeempee@xeempee-comp
                  .o+`                   --------------------
                 `ooo/                   OS: Arch Linux x86_64
                `+oooo:                  Host: Zenbook UX3402ZA_UX3402ZA 1.0
               `+oooooo:                 Kernel: 6.4.11-arch2-1
               -+oooooo+:                Uptime: 22 mins
             `/:-:++oooo+:               Packages: 1099 (pacman), 11 (flatpak), 11 (snap)
            `/++++/+++++++:              Shell: zsh 5.9
           `/++++++++++++++:             Resolution: 1920x1080
          `/+++ooooooooooooo/`           DE: GNOME 44.3
         ./ooosssso++osssssso+`          WM: Mutter
        .oossssso-````/ossssss+`         WM Theme: Adwaita
       -osssssso.      :ssssssso.        Theme: Adwaita [GTK2/3]
      :osssssss/        osssso+++.       Icons: Zafiro-Icons-Dark [GTK2/3]
     /ossssssss/        +ssssooo/-       Terminal: tmux
   `/ossssso+/:-        -:/+osssso+-     CPU: 12th Gen Intel i5-1240P (16) @ 4.400GHz
  `+sso+:-`                 `.-/+oso:    GPU: Intel Alder Lake-P
 `++:.                           `-/+/   Memory: 7244MiB / 15618MiB
`````

**EMUALTOR SCREENSHOT BUG SCREENHOT:**

[image]